# How to subscribe to Internet .ics calender with Outlook on Mac

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, macos-highsierra

I have MS Office 356 for Mac, Outlook 16.22.1. The email part is working OK. I am now trying to subscribe to calendars, but am not able to figure it out.

Using the usual mechanism of inviting someone from Outlook on Windows which emails the Mac user the webcals link, then trying to open that in Outlook on the Mac, results in the message, "There is no application set to open the URL webcals://mydom.org/calendars/mycalendar.ics".

On the Calendar "tab", ' Open Shared Calendar' is grayed out.

So, how do you do this on Mac (High Sierra 10.13.6)?

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, it is not feasible to subscribed to an internet .ics calendar using the built-in features in Outlook for Mac. If you have an Exchange account, you may add the internet calendar in OWA first, so that the calendar can be synced to your Outlook for Mac.

[image]
In case you don't have an Exchange account, you may create an outlook.com account and add it to your Outlook for Mac.

Comment: I've been given that advice about creating an outlook.com account before. But, does that mean the email will be hosted at outlook.com as well? I'm using a local IMAP server, so moving the email hosting service is not an option. Can *just* calendars be handled by an outlook.com account?

Comment: You can still use you IMAP account to handling emails. Just the subscribed calendar will be handled in the additional outlook.com account.